# clear and destroy new clone from imagemagick object, how?

Tags: imagemagick

This is a model of my code, not the full code... but good enough to ask the following question:

When i create a clone of an imagemagick object, do i have to clear and destroy that object also or just the first one. In other words, in my model code, do i need to also destroy **$clone** inside the foreach loop or just **$im** outside the loop, or both ???

Thanks

```php
function create_clone($size, $filename, $filepath)
{
   $thumb = array();
   $dir = get_dir($filename); //validate directory to write clones

   if (isset($dir)) {
      $im = new imagick($filepath);

      //create sizes of same image
      foreach ($size as $value) {
         $clone = $im->clone();

         //create clone
      }

      $im->clear();
      $im->destroy();
   }

   return $thumb;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Imagick::clear()](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pecl/imagick/trunk/imagick_class.c?view=markup#l3063) and [Imagick::destroy()](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pecl/imagick/trunk/imagick_class.c?view=markup#l3084) warp the same [ClearMagickWand](http://www.imagemagick.org/api/MagickWand/magick-wand_8c.html#ae39e4ee6ca757d764e05c2bb5e8090de) method, so you only need to call one to free allocated resources. You would need to clear, or destroy, each cloned object within the `foreach` loop. This is because cloning will only make an exact copy of the object. Clearing original resources will not free identical resources allocated to another object.

```php
$im = new imagick($filepath);

foreach ($size as $value) {
  $clone = $im->clone();

  // Do work

  $clone->clear();
}

$im->clear();
```

Also, you should use the `clone` keyword as the [method has been deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.clone.php).

```php
<?php

  // Initialize image object
  $img = new Imagick($resource);

  // Exact copy of object + data resources
  $imgCopy = clone $img;

  // Compare resource of two objects
  var_dump($img->getImageBlob() === $imgCopy->getImageBlob());
  //=> bool(true)

  // Free original object
  $img->destroy();

  // Verify original object is empty
  var_dump($img->getImageBlob());
  //=> Warning: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'Can not process empty Imagick object'

  // Verify copied object's resources are still allocated
  var_dump($imgCopy->getImageBlob());
  //=> string(342) "?PNG\r\n\032\n\000\000\000\rIHDR .... IEND?B`?"
```